# Sending less than 1 ether to verified smart contract

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, remix, etherscan

I am trying to make payable function that allows to send amount less than 1 ether. And it works in Remix where I can choose Wei/Gwei/Ether but when I verify my contract on Etherscan it allows me to enter a value only in ether (picture). Is it possible to change the minimum unit to wei?

```
`    function Stake() public payable {
         _mint(msg.sender, msg.value);     
     }`
```

[screenshot from etherscan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9wWV.jpg)

Tried to use new uint variable but I need only one

Answer (score 1):

You can input decimal numbers in the Etherscan UI - for example `0.01`.